Godot - Need to tween character movement
My character will have a broken legs at one point of the game. I want to make their movement reflect it. So that would be a kind of tween that would ease in and east out probably. How can I do that?
I have tried only moving when a step can be done for example, but I don't get that transition effect of waiting a bit before taking a step and moving positions.
Is there a way to tween the movement in the physics process?
So far I have tried to create bool variable that keeps track of when the character is allowed to make another step by listening to a signal emitted by the AnimatedSprite2D.animation_looped.
Then I tried doing a tween instead in the physics process, with no luck.
I thought about a timer approach but I have a run animation which is just a faster walk animation. So the easing there would also need to happen.
